# Methodology for Analyzing the GAP Between Provinces: Using Derived Variables and Considerations on Fixed Effects Regression

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, econometrics, fixed-effects-model, centering

I have a panel data for 106 provinces and 10 year.
I want to use a new variable created from the difference of any observation with the mean of the top 10 provinces (highest value), year by year.

It should be something like:

New Variable = Observation i at time t - Mean of the top 10 observations (at time t)

The result I should get is a variable that indicates on average how much one deviates from the top 10 provinces (GAP).

I would use this new variable in a Fixed Effects regression, as a dipendent variable.

My core questions are:

Is this a conventional or previously employed methodology? Can I find pertinent literature or guidelines on it?

Would it be methodologically right to exclude the top 10 provinces of any year from the model? I'm contemplating this due to potential divergent effect:
The gap decreases not because the worst provinces improve but because the best downgrade.

Can I possibly address this by introducing a dummy variable accounting for provinces with high score (top 10)?

This would be my final result:
[image][image]

I genuinely appreciate your insights and assistance.

Warm regards,
Lorenzo